# Example of how to create virtual account with wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

Are there any publicly available HowTos/examples of how to create/use a custom windows virtual account with WIX?

Specifically, we would like to install a service using a dedicated user account with only the permissions needed.  We would like to not have to generate or manage passwords for this account, nor can we guarantee all servers will be on a domain.

It seems virtual accounts would be a good solution, but i can not figure out how to create one in wix, or how to add groups/permissions to it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like WIX does not support virtual accounts directly.  However, a virtual account is derived from the service.  So you simply use the account `NT Service\<ServiceName>`  (where `<ServiceName>` is the name of the service using the account) when configuring the service.

For Example:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"
                          Name="OurAgent" DisplayName="our agent name"
                          Account="NT Service\OurAgent"
                          Description="Our Agent Description" Start="auto"
                          ErrorControl="critical" Interactive="no">
            <ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall="yes"/>
          </ServiceInstall>
```

After that, you can use this command to add it to the needed groups:

```
net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" /add "nt service\OurAgent"
```

Wix quiet execution tool was useful for this:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html